# Run ScalaTest feature scenarios in parallel in SBT

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, sbt, scalatest

Having `Play` project, I want to run the following tests in parallel:

```
package tests

import org.scalatest.{ParallelTestExecution, FeatureSpec}

class MyParallelTestSpec extends FeatureSpec with ParallelTestExecution {

  feature("My Feature") {
    scenario("Scenario 1") {
      println("Scenario 1.1")
      Thread.sleep(3000)
      println("Scenario 1.2")
    }
    scenario("Scenario 2") {
      println("Scenario 2")
    }
    scenario("Scenario 3") {
      println("Scenario 3.1")
      Thread.sleep(4000)
      println("Scenario 3.2")
    }
    scenario("Scenario 4") {
      println("Scenario 4")
    }
    scenario("Scenario 5") {
      println("Scenario 5")
    }
    scenario("Scenario 6") {
      println("Scenario 6")
    }
  }
}
```

In my `functionatests` module of the project opened in `IntelliJ` I define within `build.sbt` explicit parallel execution of the tests: `parallelExecution in Test := true`.

When I run in terminal: `sbt "functionaltest/main:testOnly tests.MyParallelTestSpec"` it does run in parallel but fails with these errors:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/francisk.baptista/Documents/Google/dataservices/functionaltest/target/scala-2.10/main-classes...
Scenario 6
Scenario 1.1
Scenario 3.1
Scenario 2
Scenario 4
Scenario 5
Reporter completed abruptly with an exception after receiving event: SuiteCompleted(Ordinal(0, 4, 3),DistributedTestRunnerSuite,org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite,Some(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite),Some(40),Some(MotionToSuppress),Some(TopOfClass(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite)),None,None,pool-4-thread-3,1444495674366).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected SuiteStarting for completion event: SuiteCompleted(Ordinal(0, 4, 3),DistributedTestRunnerSuite,org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite,Some(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite),Some(40),Some(MotionToSuppress),Some(TopOfClass(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite)),None,None,pool-4-thread-3,1444495674366) in the head of suite events, but we got no suite event at all
    at org.scalatest.tools.HtmlReporter.apply(HtmlReporter.scala:948)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator$$anonfun$run$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:240)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator$$anonfun$run$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:239)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator.run(DispatchReporter.scala:239)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Reporter completed abruptly with an exception after receiving event: SuiteCompleted(Ordinal(0, 8, 3),DistributedTestRunnerSuite,org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite,Some(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite),Some(41),Some(MotionToSuppress),Some(TopOfClass(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite)),None,None,pool-4-thread-7,1444495674366).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected SuiteStarting for completion event: SuiteCompleted(Ordinal(0, 8, 3),DistributedTestRunnerSuite,org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite,Some(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite),Some(41),Some(MotionToSuppress),Some(TopOfClass(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite)),None,None,pool-4-thread-7,1444495674366) in the head of suite events, but we got no suite event at all
    at org.scalatest.tools.HtmlReporter.apply(HtmlReporter.scala:948)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator$$anonfun$run$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:240)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator$$anonfun$run$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:239)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator.run(DispatchReporter.scala:239)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Reporter completed abruptly with an exception after receiving event: SuiteCompleted(Ordinal(0, 6, 3),DistributedTestRunnerSuite,org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite,Some(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite),Some(41),Some(MotionToSuppress),Some(TopOfClass(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite)),None,None,pool-4-thread-8,1444495674366).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected SuiteStarting for completion event: SuiteCompleted(Ordinal(0, 6, 3),DistributedTestRunnerSuite,org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite,Some(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite),Some(41),Some(MotionToSuppress),Some(TopOfClass(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite)),None,None,pool-4-thread-8,1444495674366) in the head of suite events, but we got no suite event at all
    at org.scalatest.tools.HtmlReporter.apply(HtmlReporter.scala:948)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator$$anonfun$run$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:240)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator$$anonfun$run$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:239)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator.run(DispatchReporter.scala:239)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Scenario 1.2
Reporter completed abruptly with an exception after receiving event: SuiteCompleted(Ordinal(0, 3, 3),DistributedTestRunnerSuite,org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite,Some(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite),Some(3039),Some(MotionToSuppress),Some(TopOfClass(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite)),None,None,pool-4-thread-5,1444495677364).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected SuiteStarting for completion event: SuiteCompleted(Ordinal(0, 3, 3),DistributedTestRunnerSuite,org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite,Some(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite),Some(3039),Some(MotionToSuppress),Some(TopOfClass(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite)),None,None,pool-4-thread-5,1444495677364) in the head of suite events, but we got no suite event at all
    at org.scalatest.tools.HtmlReporter.apply(HtmlReporter.scala:948)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator$$anonfun$run$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:240)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator$$anonfun$run$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:239)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator.run(DispatchReporter.scala:239)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Scenario 3.2
Reporter completed abruptly with an exception after receiving event: SuiteCompleted(Ordinal(0, 5, 3),DistributedTestRunnerSuite,org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite,Some(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite),Some(4040),Some(MotionToSuppress),Some(TopOfClass(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite)),None,None,pool-4-thread-4,1444495678365).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected SuiteStarting for completion event: SuiteCompleted(Ordinal(0, 5, 3),DistributedTestRunnerSuite,org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite,Some(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite),Some(4040),Some(MotionToSuppress),Some(TopOfClass(org.scalatest.tools.DistributedTestRunnerSuite)),None,None,pool-4-thread-4,1444495678365) in the head of suite events, but we got no suite event at all
    at org.scalatest.tools.HtmlReporter.apply(HtmlReporter.scala:948)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator$$anonfun$run$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:240)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator$$anonfun$run$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:239)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$Propagator.run(DispatchReporter.scala:239)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[info] Run completed in 4 seconds, 586 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 6
[info] Suites: completed 7, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 6, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[success] Total time: 17 s, completed Oct 10, 2015 5:47:58 PM
```

How can I get rid of these errors and execute the tests normally?